# Finding a backdoor on a server?

Tags: linux, detection, backdoor, rootkits

Let's say I hire someone (freelance), for IT work on an Ubuntu server. The server has a good firewall, I run clamav, chkrootkit & rkhunter scans weekly, and I try to keep good practices.

The thing is, if I suspect that he installed some backdoor on the machine, how would you search for it? He had root access and plenty of time, so...

I know this theme has been discussed earlier, but most were theoretical rather than practical answers.

NOTE: This is on a remote server, so I'm not able to do hardware-based analysis.

Comment: Really, you can't. If you suspect a server's been compromised, a clean install is the best option. There are just too many ways to hide a backdoor for there to be any reliable way of searching for them. You can't even necessarily trust the output of any commands you run.

Comment: @tlng05 I'm able to run a rescue image, which I know is legitimate, and then run diagnostics.

Comment: That helps, but the general idea still applies. There are just too many ways a backdoor can hide and many are simplistic enough to not be picked up by scanners. You need to be able to trust the people you give root access to.

Comment: @tlng05 should I delete this question? hahaha

Comment: Don't delete the question, it's useful and interesting to other people.

Answer (score 9):

To expand on @tlng05's point, rootkit authors are professionals, often with decades of experience. Unless you have decades of experience fighting rootkits, then they'll know about more hiding places than you do :P

If you suspect there's a rootkit, then your only choice is to wipe the system. This is a classic example of [Ken Thompson's reflection on trusting trust](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) "you have to trust the people, because you'll never find the exploit".

Next time, I suggest being more strict about who you give root access to.

Comment: While this is true if the defender hasn't done any preparation, you can certainly detect a rootkit if you use AIDE or a similar offline integrity checker. This is of course assuming a software rootkit.

Answer (score 3):

That highly depends on the complexity of the attack. If it's a simple backdoor, you have a chance of finding/eliminating the backdoor with the following method:

1.

```
netstat -antp
```

search for the sending port/program and remember the pid + ip.

2.

```
lsof -p <the pid>
```

look up the dies which are showing up. (These are the files used by the sending process)

3.

- Try deleting these files
- Block the IP via. iptables ([tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/))
- Change passwords of all your users
- Pray

Notice, this is **NOT** a guaranteed way to remove the backdoor. Like *[tlng05](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/54791/tlng05)* already mentioned, the most secure method would be to backup your important files and wipe the complete system. (I strongly recommend doing so too)

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the memory on your running server and do the analysis using [volatility](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility). If this server has not rebooted then you might find something interesting such as command history, strange processes, network connection ... using existing modules. I can not go into details because this is a long story and training skills to do this.

Actually, people in forensic teams use similar tools like this to investigate incidents esp IR teams.